# Check if cell value exists in two different sheets using VBA

Tags: vba

I have two different sheets that contain 500+ names on them. I need to see if the name on one sheet exists on the other. and if it does say yes or no in the specified column.

The name would be something like ASmith in one sheet, and then ASMITH in the other sheet so case sensitivity is not required.

i'm so confused on the VBA part. I program in java and to do this sort of thing in java is easy to me. But in excel, not so much. your help is appreciated. TIA

Comment: Do you only need to compare one list against the other, or both against each other?

Comment: Have you considered VLookUp http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx?

Comment: should mention the specified column on which sheet and which sheet ? why dont you explain it more easier way than we can help you instead of making assumptions

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Visual Basic does care about case sensitivity so when comparing the two sheets, you will need to convert everything to upper case using VBA.UCase. I have also included the Trim function as there may be spaces around the word itself. Any further text manipulations required to create two comparable strings will have to be researched. I would recommend this [expert guidance](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/visual-basic-text-strings.php) on manipulating text strings with Excel macros

So...assuming both the sheets are within the same workbook, the best starting point would be to get the codenames of the two sheets from within Visual Basic Editor (by default, Sheet1/Sheet2 etc.). In the below, I have assumed Sheet1 is the Output sheet, and Sheet2 is the data you are searching. If you can't fine code names, you can substitute Sheets("SheetName1") and Sheets("SheetName2") in the below code:

```
Dim SourceRow as Long
Dim DestRow as Long

For DestRow = 1 to 10
      For SourceRow = 1 to 10

            If VBA.Trim(VBA.UCase(Sheet1.Cells(DestRow,"DestCol"))) = VBA.Trim(VBA.UCase(Sheet2.Cells(SourceRow,"SourceCol"))) then
            Sheet1.Cells(DestRow,"OutputCol") = "Yes"
                  Goto NextDestRow
            End If
      Next SourceRow

Sheet1.Cells(DestRow,"OutputCol") = "No"

NextDestRow:
Next DestRow
```

The code assumes that you are searching for data in a single column in each sheet and where I've written "DestCol" and "SourceCol", you should simply insert the numeric value of that column (where A=1, B=2 etc.). "OutputCol" is the column in which you want to place the output on the destination sheet

The loop assumes you are interested in Rows 1 to 10 on each sheet; adjust as necessary

Comment: thanks so much! this made my mindless task of comparing 500 entries a little less mindless! :)

Comment: If that fully resolves your problem, it would be good if you could mark it as a complete solution. Cheers

Comment: A couple of suggested mods using Ed's approach, (i) exit the If test as soon as YesFlag =1 rather than continue redundant checking (ii) running a Find routine or using variant arrays rather than a Range loop will significantly reduce the code runtime

Comment: Nice code, I agree with brettdj's comments regarding speed, although not so bad with 500 rows. Perhaps another suggestion would be dimensioning rows as long not variant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub HTH()

    With Sheet1.Range("B1", Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet2!C[-1],1,FALSE)),""NO"",""YES"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

**NOTES**

Assumes lookup values are in sheet1 column A, the lookup column is sheet2 column A.  Places Yes/No in sheet1 column B to show if value found or not.  Vlookup is not case sensitive.  You will need to change the R1C1 references/columns to suit your workbook.

It will execute very fast.